# what color code is this?:4293202944

Tags: windows-phone-7, colors

what color code is this?:4293202944 and the color is supposed to be red

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  Did Martin answer your question?

Comment: No, im looking for a list of color codes like 4293202944

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If converted into hexadecimal, thats 0xFFE51400 which is in fact a kind of red: FF is the opacity, so it's opaque, E5 is the red channel, 14 the green, 00 the blue.

Answer (score 0):

The color format in hex looks like ARGB (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)